# Does my husband have any right to my earnings?

Tags: nikah

Assalamau Alaikkum. I'm married and working. I got married before 2 years. My husband is good and he does five times prayer. But when it comes to money he behaves differently. He wants my full salary. He had blocked my online bank account. I mean he has changed the password for internet banking and he is not sharing the password. If I ask him the password, he says no I'm your husband I should take care of all your expenses and everything and your duty is to go office and come like that. But I think as per the rule he doesn't force me to give my money to him. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I don't even know how he spends my money and for what he spends. If I ask he will say I don't have to say all to you, no such rule like that. I don't have freedom at all though I'm earning. Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere and suggest me what should I do.

Comment: This sounds more like a communication and trust issue rather than a problem with knowing the religious ruling on the matter. My advice is to figure out what the real problem is and address that.

Answer (score 6):

In Islamic law, the burden of *nafaqa* (providing for the family) lies with the man and *not* with the woman. This in effect gives the woman full control of her own money, and thus it is unlawful for a husband to demand money from his wife even though the wife my lawfully demand money from him.

Online fatwas on the matter:

- [In English](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=193269)
- [In Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/42518)